# jQuery UI Sortable connectWith multiple lists: How to update form field with the number of list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I have multiple lists working using sortable and connectWith, but I am having difficulty updating the hidden form field with the new list/column number after moving an item.

The code works fine for the updating the current position, but I can't get the Javascript working for the column number.

Here's the code I have so far:

```html
<div id='column1' class='col'>
  <div id='contentItem_1'>
    ITEM 1
    <input class='itemcurrposition' type='hidden' name='item[1][currposition]' value='1' />
    <input class='itemcolumnnum' type='hidden' name='item[1][columnnum]' value='1' />
  </div>
  <div id='contentItem_2'>
    ITEM 2
    <input class='itemcurrposition' type='hidden' name='item[2][currposition]' value='2' />
    <input class='itemcolumnnum' type='hidden' name='item[2][columnnum]' value='1' />
  </div>
</div>
<div id='column2' class='col'>
  <div id='contentItem_3'>
    ITEM 3
    <input class='itemcurrposition' type='hidden' name='item[3][currposition]' value='3' />
    <input class='itemcolumnnum' type='hidden' name='item[3][columnnum]' value='2' />
  </div>
  <div id='contentItem_4'>
    ITEM 4
    <input class='itemcurrposition' type='hidden' name='item[4][currposition]' value='4' />
    <input class='itemcolumnnum' type='hidden' name='item[4][columnnum]' value='2' />
  </div>
</div>
<div id='column3' class='col'>
  <div id='contentItem_5'>
    ITEM 5
    <input class='itemcurrposition' type='hidden' name='item[5][currposition]' value='5' />
    <input class='itemcolumnnum' type='hidden' name='item[5][columnnum]' value='3' />
  </div>
  <div id='contentItem_6'>
    ITEM 6
    <input class='itemcurrposition' type='hidden' name='item[6][currposition]' value='6' />
    <input class='itemcolumnnum' type='hidden' name='item[6][columnnum]' value='3' />
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#column1, #column2, #column3').sortable ({
    connectWith: '.col',
    stop: function () {
      var inputs2 = $('input.itemcurrposition');
      var nbElems2 = inputs2.length;
      $('input.itemcurrposition').each(function(idx) {
        $(this).val(nbElems2 - idx);
      });
    }
    })
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event and ui arguments in your "stop" event handler, use ui.item to retrieve dragged item, then set value of its input to the index of parent column.

```
stop: function (event, ui) {

  var inputs2 = $('input.itemcurrposition');
  var nbElems2 = inputs2.length;
  $('input.itemcurrposition').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).val(nbElems2 - idx);          
  });

  var newval = ui.item.closest('.col').index()+1;
  ui.item.find("input.itemcolumnnum").val(newval);              
}
```

if the column number depends on column id and not its index you can get it like this:

```
var newval = ui.item.closest('.col').attr('id').replace("column", "");
```

here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/uZR7G/) with updated code